# Is it wrong to use module.exports to export specific data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, node-modules

So, this is the first time I'm trying to take a large js app written in one file and modularize it into separate files. The goal is to create a more organized base of files rather than one big one.

There are a lot of api calls and a lot of shared information. I'm making use of module.exports but I'm not sure that it's the best way to go about it. I'd like some advice on how to do it more correctly or maybe I should use some other method? I'm using module.exports to pass back specific data rather than functions.

For example, here's the authentication function which was in the larger file and now in authenticate.js (some irrelevant parts were taken out):

```
module.exports.authenticate = (logger) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const authentication = new logger("Authentication Service"); 

    fs.createReadStream('auth.json').pipe(request.post(('https://example.com/auth'), function (error, response, body) {
      authentication.log('Authenicating API access');

      body = JSON.parse(body);

      token = body.response.token
      if (typeof(token) === 'undefined' || token === '') {
        reject('No Token Available');
      }
      authentication.log('Successfully logged in.');
      module.exports.token = token;
      resolve();
    }));
  })
}
```

So specifically, i'm using 'module.exports.token = token;' to pass back the token info that was just retrieved from the api call, I'm doing this in quite a few modules though for different pieces of information.

Is this proper and good practice? 
Thanks!

Comment: You do what you want in your app, if your app is easily updatable there is no problem. If your goal is to share a library, the encapsulation is more important

Comment: Thanks, I asked because I've never done a module.exports with something so specific so many times. It all works this way though which I'm happy with. Feels weird though. Appreciate the input!